# Python - Selenium and XPATH to extract all rows from a table

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Selenium and XPATH to extract all rows from a table, but can only get the first row.

Here is what I am doing:

```
from selenium import webdriver

path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/me/Desktop/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

url = "http://www.psacard.com/smrpriceguide/SetDetail.aspx?SMRSetID=1055"

browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

SMRtable = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="set-detail-table"]/tbody')

for i in SMRtable.find_element_by_xpath('.//tr'):
    print i.get_attribute('innerHTML')

browser.close()
```

The `SMRtable` variable has all the rows in it when I convert to string and print. When I try to loop through it, it throw a `not iterable` error.

I also tried using `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="set-detail-table"]/tbody/tr')`, but this only gives me the first row. I tried adding `[position()>0]` after `/tr`, but still got just the first row.

How can I get all of the rows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [`find_elements_by_xpath()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) (watch the "s") instead:

```
for i in SMRtable.find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr'):
    print i.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: I hate when that happen's'.  Thanks.

Comment: what is 'innerHTML ? CSS or xpath?'

Comment: using `print(i.get_attribute('innerHTML')` I get the HTML Table Code. How do I render that to DataFrame or CSV? Thanks